# how to get author comment inside the loop?

Tags: loop, comments

I want to get author comment in loop. The code is

```
<?php
$args = array(
 'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
 'posts_per_page' => '3',
 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )   );
// the query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop   
if ( $query->have_posts() )  ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post() ; ?>


        <li class="com_list">
        <a class="post-thumbnail" href="#">

     <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 32 ); ?>

       </a>
   <p><strong><a href="#">

 <?php the_author_posts_link();?>

</a> <i>says:</i></strong> author comment </p>

 </li>
```

what will be code for author comment in this loop and is my `<?php the_author_posts_link();?>` link is correct for this loop. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Nayeem Riddhi,

Use this.

```
<?php get_comments( array('author__in' => implode(',',$authors_data)) ); ?>
```

**Let me know for more information**